# Geometry editor was closed abnormally

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench

I got a terrible **error** in the **Ansys** when I try to create a **new project**.

I couldn't be able to open the geometry. Every time i open it i get the error "**Geometry editor was closed abnormally**"

I looked for the solution but didn't get the proper answer.

I useing:

Windows 10;

Ansys 19.2;

notebook Specifications:
Lenovo ideapad 320

Intel Pentium 4415U (2.3 ГГц)

RAM 4 ГБ

nVidia GeForce 920МХ

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the documentation to see if that processor in that configuration will fully support Ansys?

Comment: I checked the documentation, but did not find it.

Comment: Try on a different machine... Get a friend or colleague to open your model... work the options to narrow down the possibilities... I do wonder if that ideapad has the heavyweight processing power necessary - but I was running Ansys when its version number was below 10... and memory had to be specified as extended or expanded...

Comment: On other machine everything works fine.